# Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

> org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: No matching client found for package name 'rt'at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.action(GoogleServicesTask.java:117)

Why do I get this error?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing your google-services.json file, or there is a problem with it.

If the json file is there (app/app/google-services.json), then make sure your package id is included. If it isnt, that is likely your problem.

File should look like this:

```
"project_info": {
  "project_number": "123456789",
  "firebase_url": "https://xmpl.firebaseio.com",
  "project_id": "xmpl",
  "storage_bucket": "xmpl.appspot.com"
 },

 "client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:684654651:android:1681354132165",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.example.app"
    }
  },
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "65168135-sfas651fsad65f1sd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.example.app",
        "certificate_hash": "a16515asd1f65sd1f651sdf65"
      }
    },
```

Delete the file, make sure your app level gradle file is setup correctly.

It must contain this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Clean and then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

it is an error in you're  **google-services.json** file so, check **"package_name":** in the google-services.json file, and **package_name** should be the same as the **Firebase package name**.